# How to prove that ABC is isosceles where $\angle{BAC}=20^\circ$ and $\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc}= \min \{b,c\}$

Tags: geometry

Let $\bigtriangleup{ABC}, \angle{BAC}=20^\circ$ and $\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc}=
\min \{b,c\}$. How to prove that ABC is isosceles?
I try to use that $a^3\cos(B−C)+b^3\cos(C−A)+c^3\cos(A−B)=3abc$.

Comment: Piteer, could you write what you tried in order to solve your problem ?

Comment: @piteer, what do you mean by min{b, c}?

Comment: min{b,c} the smallest number from set {b,c}

Answer (score 2):

First, let's prove the lemma below.

---

**Lemma:** The minimum value of $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2x}{\sin(20^{\circ}+x)},$ where $x \in [80^{\circ}, 160^{\circ})$, is $\sin20^{\circ}(1+2\cos20^{\circ}).$

**Proof:** $f(x)$ is continuous, and we have:

$$f'(x)=\frac{2\sin x\cos x\sin(20^{\circ}+x)-\sin^2x\cos(20^{\circ}+x)}{\sin^2(20^{\circ}+x)}\\=\frac{\sin x(2\cos x\sin(20^{\circ}+x)-\sin x\cos(20^{\circ}+x))}{\sin^2(20^{\circ}+x)}\\=\frac{\sin x(\cos x\sin(20^{\circ}+x)+\sin 20^{\circ})}{\sin^2(20^{\circ}+x)}\\=\frac{0.5\sin x (\sin (20^{\circ}+2x)+3\sin 20^{\circ})}{\sin^2(20^{\circ}+x)}>0,$$

where $x \in [80^{\circ}, 160^{\circ})$ because:
$$\sin (20^{\circ}+2x)+3\sin 20^{\circ} \geq -1+3\sin 20^{\circ} >0.$$

Therefore,
$$f(x) \geq f(80^{\circ})=\sin 80^{\circ}=\sin20^{\circ}(1+2\cos20^{\circ}).$$

---

Now, assume $c\geq b$, so $160^{\circ}> \angle  C \geq 80^{\circ}$.

And,

$$a^3+c^3=3abc \implies a(b^2+c^2-2bc \cos 20^{\circ})+c^3=3abc\\ \implies ab^2+ac^2+c^3=abc(3+2\cos 20^{\circ}) \\ \implies \frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{c^2}{ab}=3+2\cos 20^{\circ}.$$

But on the other hand by the lemma above and a very simple application of AM-GM:

$$\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b} \geq 2, \\ \frac{c^2}{ab}=\frac{\sin ^2 \angle C}{\sin 20^{\circ} \sin (20^{\circ}+\angle C)} \geq 1+2\cos20^{\circ},$$

which gives $b=c$ and $\angle C=80^{\circ}.$

We are done.

Comment: That's a nice tricky solution. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality let $b\le c$. We have $\cos 20^\circ = \dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$. Using the triple-angle formula $\cos 3\varphi = 4\cos^3 \varphi - 3 \cos \varphi$ we find
$$\frac 12 = \cos 60^\circ = 4\cos^3 20^\circ - 3\cos 20^\circ = 4\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)^3-3\cdot \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}.$$
Clearing denominators we obtain
$$0=a^6-3a^4(b^2+c^2)+3a^2(b^2+bc+c^2)-b^6+b^3c^3-c^6.$$
We are given $a^3=3abc-c^3$. Substituting this to RHS we get
\begin{align*}
0&=(3abc-c^3)^2-3a(3abc-c^3)(b^2+c^2)+3a^2(b^4+b^2c^2+c^4)-b^6+b^3c^3-c^6 \\
&=3a^2(b^4-3b^3c+4b^2c^2-3bc^3+c^4)+3ac^3(b^2-2bc+c^2)+b^3(c^3-b^3)\\
&=3a^2(b-c)^2(b^2-bc+c^2)+3ac^3(b-c)^2+b^3(c^3-b^3) \\
&\ge 0
\end{align*}
with equality if and only if $b=c$.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty of this problem, (at least for me who has spent a lot of time solving it) consists of wanting to use the equality $b=\dfrac{a^3+c^3}{3ac}$ to derive the result, which leads to complicated calculations. The matter turned out to be the other way around: we can show that, in every isosceles triangle with a minor angle equal to twenty degrees, the property is verified. We are done if we have previously underlined the fact that in the capable arc corresponding to side BC there is only one isosceles triangle.

In the attached figure, the corresponding (red) arc capable of the segment $\overline{BC}$ which play the role of side $a$ of our triangle $\triangle {ABC}$. We have
$$\overline{AC}=2r\cos(10^{\circ})\\\overline{BC}=2r\sin(20^{\circ})$$ and we finish verifying that $$\frac{(\overline{AC})^3+(\overline{BC})^3}{3\overline{AC}\cdot\overline{BC}}=\overline{AC}$$ i.e.
$$\frac{(2r\cos(10^{\circ}))^3+(2r\sin(20^{\circ})^3}{3\cdot2r\cos(10^{\circ})\cdot2r\sin(20^{\circ})}=2r\cos(10^{\circ})$$ which reduces to $$1+8\sin^3(10^{\circ})=6\sin(10^{\circ})$$ This is true each member being equal to $1.041889066$.

Thus it is a property that characterizes every isosceles triangle whose minor angle measures twenty degrees.

[image]

Comment: I found that solution but i don't now khow soomeone did it $\frac{\sin^2 20^\circ}{\sin B \sin (160^\circ - B)}+\frac{\sin^2 B}{\sin 20^\circ \sin (160^\circ -B)}=3 ,$
so $B=80^\circ$ $ \Rightarrow $ $ C=80^\circ $

Comment: @piteer What you say is nonsense herein. I don't need to show that $B=C$. Look at the arc capable of segment $BC$ for angle of $20^{\circ}$ where it is clear that there is only one isosceles triangle. If you can show that the equality holds for another triangle  with vertex in the arc capable (impossible due to the calculations in play) then you would be showing that the property is false and that was not requested by the OP. The relation $b=\dfrac{a^3+c^3}{3ac}$ characterize all these isosceles triangles.

Comment: @piteer If you want to solve this problem in another way, without the capable arc, I suggest what I had done three times before but didn't realize at the end and thought of an error in my calculations. Choose, let's say, the side $b\lt c$ and then calculate as you wish. What will happen to the angle $\gamma$ opposite the side $c$? (suite)

Comment: (suite) It came out that its cosine is greater than $1$, so I thought I had made a mistake when calculating. BUT NO, it happens that this was a proof by contradiction and then the $b$-side was not the minor one. So by choosing the side $c\lt b$, the calculations (which you don't need to do) will be the same and you will also arrive at the same contradiction with the angle$\beta$. END OF YOUR PROOF.